# How can I migrate code from org.json library to codename one's json parser?

Tags: codenameone

I managed to get the JSON text in a String, and that's ok.

It looks like this :

> {"contacts":[{"id":"1","name":"Andrew","surname":"AAAAA","address":"red street 12","phone1":"312312312","phone2":"0123232"}, "id":"0","name":"Marco","surname":"Gioia","address":"blue street 3","phone1":"12345678","phone2":"123456789"}]}

What I used to do to extract a name was simply :

```
JSONObject nodeRoot = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray nodeStats = nodeRoot.getJSONArray("contacts");
String name = nodeStats.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
```

But using external jars looks messy in cn1, and not something you really want to prefere.
How can I handle this with cn1 json parser?

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

Use the cn1json cn1lib.  It is a port of org.json

Add it to your project using codename one settings in the extensions section.